# Property of .net web server control not showing in design mode

Tags: .net, controls, webserver, designmode

I have a Label on a .Net page.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

The control has the Style-property, but this is not shown if I try to set a property in markup/design mode (I think the tool is called IntelliSense). I would like to know

- why this is so
- if there are any other properties not showing up you know of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found some explanation. Look [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/108390/style-does-not-appear-in-intellisense-attribute-list-nor-in-property-grid).